# How to implement mouseleave in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a small problem with sliding in jquery. On **hover** (mouse over), I need my navigation list item to show its content by sliding down and on mouse out it should slide up.

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
     <li  id = "mousehover">
       <a style="background-color:#f78144; color: #000; text-align:  center;" href="#">Time Table
      </a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div id = "hovercontent">
     Contents 1 
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#mousehover").mouseenter(function(){
        $("#hovercontent").slideDown("slow");
    });

    $("#hovercontent").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).slideUp("slow");
    });

 });
</script>
```

Here the problem is when I **hover** on the list the div slides down, but only after I hover on the div and get out of the nav the div is sliding up. I need the div to slide up even if I mouse out of the list with out entering the div. How can this be done?

Comment: Ya i have. Only one thing has to be changed and tht is exactly im looking for. When ever I hover on time table the content 1 is displayed. But only after I get in to the content and get out of it, the content is sliding up. but I need the content 1 to slide up even if i get out of timetable with out touching content1.

Comment: Only exception is when i leave timetable and enter in to content1 alone it should not slide up. I should have access to it. But if I leave time table with out touching content it should slide up. Hope you got it.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use `mouseover` and `mouseout` will do it for you..

```
$("#hovercontent").bind("mouseout", function() {
     $(this).slideUp("slow");
});
```

Comment: use .on() instead of .bind() for more flexible Event binding

Answer (score 0):

Try this and put it in the `doc ready` this way: http://jsfiddle.net/ptVbs/

```
$("#mousehover").hover(function() {
    $("#hovercontent").slideDown("slow");
}, function() {
    if (!$("#hovercontent").hover()) {
        $("#hovercontent").slideUp("slow");
    }
});
$("#hovercontent").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).slideUp("slow");
});
```

you can try it out in fiddle.

Comment: Ya i have. Only one thing has to be changed and tht is exactly im looking for. When ever I hover on time table the content 1 is displayed. But only after I get in to the content and get out of it, the content is sliding up. but I need the content 1 to slide up even if i get out of timetable with out touching content1.

Comment: Only exception is when i leave timetable and enter in to content1 alone it should not slide up. I should have access to it. But if I leave time table with out touching content it should slide up. Hope you got it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a class:

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
    <li  id = "mousehover" class="menu1">
       <a style="background-color:#f78144;color:#000;text-align:center;" href="#">Time Table</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div id = "hovercontent" class="menu1">
    Contents 1 
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mousehover").mouseenter(function(){
        $("#hovercontent").slideDown("slow");
    });

    $(".menu1").mouseout(function(){
        $("#hovercontent").slideUp("slow");
    });
});​
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html. In your eventhandlers, check for the relatedTarget as described there. Use console.log in the eventhandlers to track what's happening. Unfortunately, I can't help further without having the CSS for the classes you use... maybe you could provide a testcase in JSBin at http://jsbin.com/ ?

Comment: Thank you. Let me try this.:)

Answer (score 0):

try it with `event.type` on `'hover'`
You attach an 'hover' event Handler on your `#mousehover` content, and with `event.type` you see what event type is going on. With the Event `'hover'` you get *mouseenter* and *mouseleave*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    ​$('#mousehover').on('hover',function(event){
        switch(event.type){
            case 'mouseenter': $("#hovercontent").slideDown("slow");
                break;
            case 'mouseleave': $("#hovercontent").slideUp("slow");
                break;
        }
    });​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#mousehover").mouseover(function(){
      $("#hovercontent").slideDown("slow");
   });
   $("#hovercontent ,#mousehover").mouseleave(function(){
       $('#hovercontent').slideUp("slow");
   });

});
```